# Find angle in a triangle given angle bisector and altitude without trigonometry.

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

In the triangle $ABC$, $BM$ is altitude and $E$ is in that segment such that $CE$ is angle bisector. Also, the angle $EAM = 30º$ and the angle $MCB = 20º$. Find the value of $ABM$.

[image]

My problem with this exercise is that it has to be done without trigonometry. I did it with trigonometry and I got that the answer is $40º$ (if i am not mistaken). Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: @poetasis why can you assume that E is the incenter?i dont think that holds here ?

Comment: @Trobeli If you want a solution by analytical geometry (coordinates), it is very easy. But the problem with angles in general cannot be done with Euclidean geometry, in most cases that is typical of trigonometry.

Comment: @poetasis You are wrong.

Comment: @poetasis By that logic $BE$ is also angle bisector giving $\angle ABM = \angle CBM = 70^\circ$. But $BE$ is altitude. $E$ is just the meeting point of $C$-bisector and $B$-altitude and $A$ is joined to it. If $AE$ were $A$-bisector, it would meet $C$-bisector at the point where $B$-bisector also meets, namely the incenter $I$.

Comment: @Trobeli Extending the line $CE$ until, say, $C'$, you do have $\angle{C'EA}=40^{\circ}$ so if you can show that $\angle{C'EA}=\angle{ABM}$ you are done. But how to do this by "pure" geometry?

Comment: To everyone. I acknowledge my error and I hope I have made better assumptions in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, when angles are nice multiples of $10^\circ$ or $\,20^\circ$, looking for a suitable equilateral $\triangle$ will usually lead you to a solution.

**Solution :** Take $E'$ symmetric to $E$ wrt to $BC$. So $\angle E'AM=\angle EAM=30^\circ$, $\angle E'CM=\angle ECM=10^\circ$. We see $\triangle EAE'$ is equilateral and $\angle BCE' = 30^\circ$.

[image]

One great thing about an angle of a $\triangle$ being equal to $30^\circ$ is that its opposite side subtends $60^\circ$ at the circumcenter, forming an equilateral $\triangle$. So let $O$ be the circumcenter of $\triangle BCE'$. In figure, $\triangle BOE'$ has $\angle BOE'=2\angle BCE'=60^\circ$ and $OB,OE'$ are equal circumradii $ \Rightarrow \triangle BOE'$ is equilateral.

Now a property about altitude and circumradius from same vertex is, they make equal angles with adjacent sides as can be seen in the following diagram.

[image]

Thus $CO$ makes with side $CB$ same angle altitude $CM$ makes with side $CE'$ (in first diagram). $\angle OCB = \angle MCE' = 10^\circ = \angle BCE$. This means $O$ lies on $EC\,!$

Now we focus on the colored $\triangle OEE'$ and $\triangle BAE'$. With $OE'=BE'$, $\angle OE'E = 60^\circ = \angle BE'A$, $EE'=AE'$, the two triangles are congruent and $$\angle ABM = \angle ABE' = \angle EOE' = 180^\circ - 80^\circ - 60^\circ = 40^\circ \quad \square$$

Comment: i followed everything, but I didn't catch why the circumcenter of $BCE'$ is in the segment $CE$

Comment: $OC$ is a segment at $10^\circ$ from $BC$ inside the triangle but $EC$ is the line at $10^\circ$ from $BC$ inside the triangle. Such a line is unique meaning $OC$ is a part of $EC$ or $O$ lies on $EC$. @Trobeli

Answer (score 1):

An alternative ending to [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4770880/139123), borrowing the figure from that answer and starting at the point where it has been proved that $\triangle BOE'$ is equilateral:

[image]

Since $\triangle AEE'$ is equilateral, $E'A \cong E'E$. Also, $E'B \cong E'O$
and $\angle AE'B \cong \angle EE'O$, so by side-angle-side,
$\triangle AE'B \cong \triangle EE'O$
and therefore $\angle ABM \cong \angle ABE' \cong \angle EOE'$.
But
$$ \angle EOE' = 180^\circ - 80^\circ - 60^\circ = 40^\circ. $$

Therefore $\angle ABM = 40^\circ.$